# How to update a metadata list field using PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, pnp-js-core

I'm trying to update a list item field that is Managed metadata field using PnP-JS-Core. First I was getting this error:

```
pnp.min.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular
structure to JSON
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at pnp.min.js:10
(anonymous) @ pnp.min.js:10
```

But I realized, If PnP-JS-Core is based in API REST so, let's use the API REST format. I'm trying to pass an object like:

```
var myObject = {
        __metadata: {"type" : "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue"},
        Label: term.get_name(),
        TermGuid: term.get_id().toString(),
        WssId: -1
};
```

Now I don't get an error now but the field is not updated.

someone can help with this?

Comment: This question has been answered on another thread. You can find a solution using the link below. It worked for me. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/244206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it.
I opened a ticket in the official github site and the answer they gave didn't work for me and other user trying to do the same.

Apparently it's only working for items that has only one managed metadata property, I have more than one field in my lists.

Issue: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/issues/295

I had to do it using JSOM.