# Trying to update Managed metadata column value in sharepoint library using pnp js

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, pnp, pnp-js-core

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ListName").items.getById(1).update({
    Title: Title,
    DeptDiv://internal name of list column 
   {
      __metadata: 
     { 
         "type": "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" },
          Label: Department1,//value to be updated
          TermGuid: "**********************",
          WssId: -1,
     }
   }).then(r => {

    console.log(r);
});
```

Comment: is it a single value taxonomy field or multi-valued field ? The code seems to be fine and works for me in SPO, whats the error ?

Comment: Getting the following Error:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
exceptions.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [400] 
    at new ProcessHttpClientResponseException (exceptions.js:24)
    at core.js:37

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the values for the fields in quotes.

Modify your code as below:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ListName").items.getById(1).update({
    Title: "Some title",
    DeptDiv: //internal name of list column 
   {
      __metadata: 
     { 
         "type": "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" },
          Label: "Department1", //value to be updated
          TermGuid: "**********************",  // guid of the term label(not termset)
          WssId: -1,
     }
   }).then(r => {

    console.log(r);
});
```

Comment: Department1 is a variable.

Comment: it needs to be a string. Also, the term should exist in the term set. Try hard-coding a term label guid and label and check.

Comment: TermGuid: its the termset unique identifier right? or the labels unique identifier. Taxonomy->Term Group->Department(Termset)->Term label.   I am using the GUid if Termset.

Comment: it should be the guid of the term inside the termset i.e term label ( Department(Termset)-> **Term label** ) --- guid of the Term label

Comment: Getting the following Error:"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
exceptions.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [400] 
    at new ProcessHttpClientResponseException (exceptions.js:24)"   I have checked all the internal names are correct.

Comment: are you using the correct label name and its guid ? The term label should belong to the term set which is associated with the list column

Comment: pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('LEG Library').items.getById(+DocumentID).validateUpdateListItem([{
            ErrorMessage: null,
            FieldName: "DocCountry",
            FieldValue: +DocumentCountry+"|LabelGUID",
            
            HasException: false
          }]);                                                                                                                                         This one worked.. Is there a way to get Guid on the go dynamically instead of hard codeing..  Here DocmentCountry i am fetching it from a drop down populated by managed metadata.

Comment: You can use JSOM to get the guid of the term because REST support is quite limited unfortunately :(